# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I change http to https

Tags: https

How to install WordPress to https from scratch whithout **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error?

I'm on Plesk panel, and I have upload WordPress files directly on my FTP.

When I go to the installation page, I have one problem with style or **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error.

Comment: did you add something in your htaccess or are you using the default one ?

Comment: I'm using the default .htaccess file.

Comment: try to add this in your htaccess : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>